# 2d array throws an exception, out of bound and cannot assign values?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
            SolidColorBrush White = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0));

            SolidColorBrush[,] UPPSide = new SolidColorBrush[3, 3];
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; i <3; j++)
            {
                UPPSide[i, j] = White;
            }
        }

        List<SolidColorBrush[,]> theCube = new List<SolidColorBrush[,]> { UPPSide, FRTSide, DWNSide, BCKSide, LFTSide, RGTSide };
```

This is one of the sides of the Rubik's cube, i declared "white" as the color and made a 2d array [3*3] to assign the colors in so i could rotate it, but there was an out of bound exception, I don't realise what the problem is though.
Please let me know if i phrased anything unclear, not a good question maker.
edited
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wFhm.png)

i think thats the program running and stopped

Comment: Rather than learning the answer to this question, you should first be learning how to debug. Stick a break point on that line in your inner loop. Spin it up look at the values of your variables and your comparison. Run to the next time the break point is hit. What's going on? 3*3 is 9 so it's not like you're iterating a million times in complex code.

Comment: thanks, i have a lot mor eto learn about how to use the features of VS in depths : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the "out of bounds" exception is because you have a typo on your inner `for` loop. You wrote `i <3` instead of `j <3`.

Change it to this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j <3; j++)
    {
        UPPSide[i, j] = White;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks mate. But i changed the thingy its still out of bound

Comment: That's strange, because I tested it myself and after making the modification, I no longer got your out of bounds exception. Are you sure you're not getting a NEW out of bounds exception on some OTHER line of code? Visual Studio should tell you exactly the line of code where the exception occurs. Check its Error window and it will tell you where the problem is.